# How would I update a field based on 3 other fields in react?js

Tags: reactjs

I want to update the values of one field based on 3 other fields. 
Currently, **amount charged / currency / year** must be filled in, once it is, the USD value field updates and it's value changes to the **amount charged multiplied by the year**

**CODE**

https://codesandbox.io/s/r5n7964ooq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to automatically update value of USD only if other 3 values are available.

Code : https://codesandbox.io/s/8zv2v5mr22

Let me know if this is currect.